# jQuery determine if ul has class OR another one

Tags: jquery, if-statement

what is the right way to determine if an object has one class OR another one?
The following is appearantly wrong..

```
if ($('#menu-item-49').hasClass('current-menu-item' || 'current-menu-parent') ) {
  $('ul.sub-menu ').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 75):

You could use [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) instead?

```
if ($('#menu-item-49').is('.current-menu-item, .current-menu-parent')) {
  $('ul.sub-menu ').css('display', 'block');
}
```

> Check the current matched set of
>   elements against a selector and return
>   true if at least one of these elements
>   matches the selector.

Beats having to use multiple `hasClass` queries, which is the alternative:

```
if ($('#menu-item-49').hasClass('current-menu-item') || 
    $('#menu-item-49').hasClass('current-menu-parent')) {
  $('ul.sub-menu ').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Comment: Sure is! Better than writing hasClass() || hasClass || hasClass over and over.

Comment: Did you mean to place the comma inside the quotes? `'.current-menu-item, .current-menu-parent'` Currently the second argument is ignored.

Comment: a performance comparison for the performance conscious : [jsperf is vs hasClass for multiple classes](https://jsperf.com/is-vs-hasclass-for-multiple-classes/5)

Comment: Use classlist.contains for even better performance - http://jsperf.com/is-vs-hasclass-for-multiple-classes/6

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the `||` (or) operator within `hasClass`. Try this:

```
if ($('#menu-item-49').hasClass('current-menu-item') || 
    $('#menu-item-49').hasClass('current-menu-parent')) {
  $('ul.sub-menu ').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Or you can do this if that's too verbose:

```
var $menuItem = $('#menu-item-49');
if ($menuItem.hasClass('current-menu-item') || 
    $menuItem.hasClass('current-menu-parent')) {
  $('ul.sub-menu ').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Or even better:

```
var $menuItem = $('#menu-item-49');
if ($menuItem.is('.current-menu-item, .current-menu-parent')) {
  $('ul.sub-menu ').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Comment: In your last version, shouldn't the comma be inside the quotes? `'.current-menu-item,.current-menu-parent'` I'm pretty sure `is()` only accepts 1 argument, but the other answer with this solution did the same thing, so now I'm starting to doubt myself. :o)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#menu-item-49').hasClass('current-menu-item') || $('#menu-item-49').hasClass('current-menu-parent') ) {
  $('ul.sub-menu ').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Have you tried the following?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.is()` to check for any class beginning with `current-menu-` by using:

```
if ( $('#menu-item-49').is('[class]^="current-menu-"') ) {
    //49 is the current menu!
}
```

More attribute selectors like `^=` may be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

Comment: There's a problem with this snippet, syntax-wise. It should rather be:


if ( $('#menu-item-49').is('[class^="current-menu-"]') ) {
    //49 is the current menu!
}

Answer (score 0):

The following is what you've in mind:

```
var menuItem49 = $('#menu-item-49');
if (menuItem49.hasClass('current-menu-item') || menuItem49.hasClass('current-menu-parent')) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So close!

Try:

```
if ($('#menu-item-49').hasClass('current-menu-item') || $('#menu-item-49').hasClass('current-menu-parent') ) {
  $('ul.sub-menu ').css('display', 'block'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this instead, separating it in two bits:

```
if ($('#menu-item-49').hasClass('current-menu-item') || $('#menu-item-49').hasClass('current-menu-parent') ){
   $('ul.sub-menu ').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Hope this helps you