# Grep strings in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery object (thisClass) that contains 2 or more class names. I am trying to figure out how to return only the class name that is in a predetermined array.

Something like this:

```
var thisClass = $(this).attr("class");
var icons = ["glass","leaf","dog","home"];

[Use grep here to return thisClass only as a single class name that is filtered by, or contained in icons.]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196613/jquery-determine-if-ul-has-class-or-another-one what you're looking for?

Comment: I think you are looking for the class method. http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, first of all, `attr` method returns string not a jQuery object. In this case, it returns string with all CSS classes separate with space. If there is no class, it returns `undefined`. So, you may want try this code:

```
var thisClass = $(this).attr("class");
var result = [];

if(thisClass) {
    thisClass = thisClass.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < thisClass.length; i++) {
        if(icons.indexOf(thisClass[i]) !== -1) {
            result.push(thisClass[i]);
        }
    }
} else {
    // return; or something. There is no classes.
}
```